# How to allow only valid values to an integer like object and stil iterate over it?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, wrapper

In a project I'm beginning I created a class that is basically a wrapper around an integer type. I choose to do this for a couple of reasons. First I want to add methods to it that will tell me something specific about my value. For example I could have a method named `is_odd()` (This is just an example. Second, I want to check that the values are always within a valid range.

So my class may look like this :

```
class C {
public:
   // Constructor and some other stuff here including
   // post and pre increment operators

   inline void CheckInvariant() const
   { assert(0 <= value_ && value_ <= 8);};
private:
   std::uint8_t value_;
};
```

Now I want to iterate over all possible values of this class. Like this :

```
for (C c(0); c <= c::max_value; ++c)
{
   // Do something
}
```

Or even like this :

```
// Note here that C::min_value <= c is always true
// because the value wrap-around. 
for (C c = C::max_value; C::min_value <= c; --c)
{
   // Do something
}
```

The problem is that c becomes invalid when it is incremented past `c::max_value` and since I call 'CheckInvariant()` from the operator++ it fails.

I first tough I could put all valid values in an array an iterate over that, but the code that will use this is really performance critical and this need to be as fast as using an integer directly, with the added benefit of being bound checked in debug mode (assert).

Now I understand it "smells" and my design is flawed. Is there any known pattern that would allow me to guards against invalid value and still allows to iterate efficiently trough all values?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just check your invariants in the dereference operator rather than increment/decrement.

Comment: you can write an iterator for your class and just use the range for loop.

Comment: @yngum I tough about this, but am I correct in thinking that it would be less efficient than just increment an integer? This code will be used in a really performance critical loop.

Comment: @MathieuPagé maybe, but I wouldn't worry too much about it before profiling.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you actually have TWO invariants here, not one.

The first is that if you access the value it must be within the specified range. The second is that after an increment it must be no more than one-past-the-specified range. I believe your best approach is two invariant checks, for those two conditions.

Finally note that member functions like `is_odd` are not the correct way to implement such functionality. They should be implemented as free-function algorithms instead, to provide general purpose code rather than tightly coupled to your class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right about the fact I have two invariants and one should allow values one past the range. is_odd was an example used here to abstract my real class functionality. Thanks for your answer. I'll upvote it for now and maybe accept it later.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works when iterating through *all possible values* of an integer type.

```
C c(0);
do
{
   // Do something
}
while( ++c != c(0) );
```

Note that this do-while solution assumes that the range of allowable values isn't *the empty set*.